# what do folks do to celebrate reputation milestones?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

One must watch in awe, of course, at the SO users with the highest reps, many tens of thousands. But for the rest of us, smaller achievements are still worth celebrating :-).

I just crossed the 1000-point milestone on Stack Overflow today and was walking around with a bit more spring in my step. In fact, the first thing I did when I arrived at my office was to send out a department-wide meeting invitation for a combined cubicle-warming (it's a long story) and SO milestone celebration for myself. The meeting was scheduled from 10:55 to 10:59 -- yes, I do mean four *minutes* because folks are just rather busy nowadays, and I thought could catch more people in the gap between other meetings.

It was great fun; I served snacks; I shot some video of it; lots of colleagues walked by to offer congratulations; a few even knew what Stack Overflow was (I and others eagerly espoused praise for SO to those that did not.)

**So my question is:** *what have you done to celebrate your SO milestones?*

Comment: Post the video or it didn't happen.

Comment: @Greg: You mean Vidz or it didnt happen

Comment: I'll tell you 7 rep from now. I'm almost to 5K, and we'll see what happens.

Comment: related - [Should Jon Skeet get a prize for being first to reach 100k rep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23244/should-jon-skeet-get-a-prize-for-being-first-to-reach-100k-rep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just congratulate myself and carry on with next questions to get more rep ;)

Since this is your first kind of milestone, it seems huge, but soon it will turn out to be "just another milestone". In short you will get used to it ;). I bet you will enjoy more in answering and helping and learning more than looking out for milestones. You continue to learn and share and milestones are just formality which come your way with time.

Answer (score 10):

I go earn more rep before the next recalc takes away my milestone.

Comment: I recalc'c my own rep about five times as I was approaching 65,536 because I wanted to know when I passed it *for real*.  :)

Comment: Hahahahaha!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

The only one I ever cared about, I took a screen grab.

[image]

Comment: Wow. And the Beta message to the top right (and the age) confirm it's for real!

Answer (score 3):

I always take a short break.

Then I get back at it.  The more rep I get, the longer of a break I take.  Right now I'm on a short hiatus after hitting 30K.

Comment: Not a very good hiatus - You just went to meta instead.

Comment: @ughoav, I take a hiatus from answering, not viewing or meta....(oops)

Answer (score 2):

I wore my Stack Overflow T-shirt to school on hitting 16k rep just in time for the first day.

Other times I take screenshots, especially every 5k or 10k rep.

Answer (score 1):

I go to one of the other trilogy sites and see which one I'm close to a milestone at and work on that for a little while.

Answer (score 0):

I will look for the next milestone or badge and work towards it.